# Is there a way to detect the current workspace in a command line on linux?

Tags: linux, fluxbox

I need a command on linux (my window manager is fluxbox) that gives the current workspace as output (if possible, a simple output, as i need this information for a python script).

I checked fluxbox's man (manual) and it gives little information, and when searching for this online, it only explained how to do it on another window manager.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this? Like the FQDN? `hostname` would print out the name of the actual machine, or do you mean with like 4 spaces, which of the 4 you would be on?

Comment: No, i meant that i needed a command that gives me the number of the current workspace i am on, Arkadiusz Drabczyk method worked, i just didn't knew the command wmctrl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fluxbox` is [EWMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints) compliant window manager and that means we can use tools such as `wmctrl` to interact with it. To find current workspace:

```
$ wmctrl -d | grep '*' | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

`man wmctrl` says:

> -d List all desktops managed by the window manager. (...) The second
>          column contains a '*' character for the current desktop,
>          otherwise it contains a '-' character

**EDIT**: I just checked that you can name a workspace a single `*`. In that case the above command would return two results. Use `awk`:

```
$ wmctrl -d | awk '{ if ($2 == "'*'") print $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks, Arkadiusz, i didn't knew the command 'wmctrl'.

So to get the current workspace on fluxbox, you can use:
**wmctrl -d | awk '{ if ($2 == "'*'") print $0}'**

Answer (score 0):

shortway to @arkadiusz-drabczyk is using this code

`$ wmctrl -d | awk '$2=="*"'`

awk explanation:

- `'$2=="*"'`, awk will look this pattern
- print is default action for awk, its like `{print $0}`, so dont need to write it unless you want print specific argument, like first words with `$1`

more detail about pattern in this link :https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Pattern-Overview